# Field is causing parent to expand and overflow after value is populated

Tags: css, material-ui, antd

I have a card within a parent Box of width 100%.  The card is width 45% with padding Left and Right 18px.  Inside the card, I have an Ant Design Tree Select.  It's width is 100%.  This Tree select is componentized and is called as `<Taxonomy />`.

When I fetch data using `await fetch()` and then pass a TaxonomyID into Taxonomy, another `await fetch()` must take place within the Taxonomy Component.  This happens after all other fields are rendered and populated with data from the first fetch.  The taxonomy value is populated a second or two later.  This is causing an issue with my UI.

The Taxonomy width is 100%, but when it is finally populated, it expands further, causing the card to expand.  This is causing a lot of overflow in my UI (even though I have `overflow: none;` on parent).

I can stop this from happening by setting a static width on Taxonomy (e.g. 300px), but I would rather user % as this looks better as the screen is resized.

Is it possible to calculate a static width before the taxonomy field is populated based in the width of it's parent in CSS?

See the screenshots at the bottom for a before and after

This is a quick example:

```
<Box id="page-container">
    <Box id="top-content-container">
        <Box id="title-card-container">
            <Card id="title-card">
                <Grid container spacing={6}>
                    <Grid item md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                        <Taxonomy
                            className="taxonomy"
                            // className={classes.taxonomyShape}
                            value={details?.TaxonomyID || ""}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Card>
        </Box>
    </Box>
</Box>
```

CSS:

```
#page-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px 0 30px;
    overflow-x: none;
}

#top-content-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 24px;
    width: 100%;
}

#title-card-container {
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#title-card {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px 18px 0 18px;
}

.taxonomy {
    width: 100%; 
    /* width: 300px; */
}
```

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image]